# Read config values set in ejabberd.yml programmatically

Tags: erlang, yaml, config, ejabberd

I'd like to read the value of a setting in the ejabberd.yml file and was wondering if I could still use application:get_env(ejabberd, ) to do so, as I was able to do from the ejabberd.cfg file which is a collection of erlang terms.

Any clues? I've tried searching and when I try using the application:get_env() call, I get back the value 'undefined' ...

I'm thinking that it must be a simple thing to do, and would appreciate all help!

Thanks,
Ombud.